# Getting around circular dependency

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Could I get help with a little issue I am encountering regarding splitting projects into different tiers. In my ViewModel logic I have code where I create a new instance of a window when a button is clicked (I use ICommand interface for that)

The problem is however, that this requires my View folder which is in the presentation layer, I can’t reach it as my presentation layer is dependent on my ViewModel in the logic layer.

I would just move the code that deals with the creation of the pages to the view code behind but I also pass the current instance of a viewmodel as a parameter for that new window being created (for eventhandling purposes).

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Do not "*create a new instance of a window*" in a view model. Instead, expose an event or a property, and (in the view layer) create a new window when the event is fired or the property changes its value.

Comment: Instead of creating a window, you usually would create a new ViewModel object and bind this to a presentation using a `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A view model shouldn't create instances of windows. What you could do is to inject your view model with a service that is responsible for creating windows, e.g.:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private readonly IWindowService _windowService;

    public MainWindowViewModel(IWindowService windowService)
    {
        _windowService = windowService;
        CreateWindowCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
            _windowService.CreateWindow(new SomeViewModel());
        });
    }

    public ICommand CreateWindowCommand { get; }
}
```

Define the `IWindowService` interface in the view model project and the concrete implementation of it in the view/presentation project:

```
public class WindowService : IWindowService
{
    public void CreateWindow(SomeViewModel vm)
    {
        Window win = new Window();
        win.DataContext = vm;
        win.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: My only issue with this is that when creating a new window I would use e.g. new MyPage(); which would be in my presentation layer (which is dependent on my service layer) and would be inaccessible as my VM is in my service layer. Am i wrong? I did try your code before speaking btw, thanks for sharing it!

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The presentation layer should reference the service layer but not the other way around.

Comment: I agree with you! Thats what I mean, if my View is in presentation layer and my ViewModel is in my service layer then I cannot reference a view in my WindowService class (as it is in my service layer) Unless you were implying for me to have the WindowService in my presentation layer? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. The *implementation* of the windows service, i.e. the `WindowService` class, should be imlemented in the view layer as I stated in my answer. Only the interface should be implemented in the view model project.